# How to render react images on django

Tags: reactjs, django, image, render, helper

After developing my react application, i decided to render it in my django using the npm run build command, which I have successfully done and it's working efficiently. But the only problem is that my images are not being rendered. Please any suggestion on how i can make django render my images. Django keeps saying this `"Not Found: /images/blog/b2.webp [08/Aug/2023 17:43:02] "GET /images/blog/b2.webp HTTP/1.1" 404 3104"` each time the app runs

I created  a static root to render all static files and also a media root for all media files. Here is the code

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reactapp/myschool/build/static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reactapp/myschool/build/media')
```